# Apache/PHP Internal Server Error (500) with possibility related to memory issue

Tags: php, apache, memory

I just moved to a new shared webhosting (PHP 7.0), moved all my files and data from the old one, and then I have this problem on my new server :

I have several PHP pages (eg. mypage1.php), which after being loaded in client webbrowser, will load another my PHP pages (via XHR/XMLHttpRequest, eg. mypage2.php, mypage3.php, ..., mypage7.php) to get some data (lets say JSON).

When I tried to access mypage1.php in my webbrowser, it gives correct response, but when the browser tried to load mypage2.php, mypage3.php, ..., mypage7.php , it returns "internal server error 500" (server error log: Mon Jul 03 01:50:07.747401 2017] [:error] [pid 612239:tid 139731694188288] (12)Cannot allocate memory: [client x.x.x.x:x] couldn't create child process: /usr/sbin/suphp for /xxx ...). The error 500 only occurs on some pages (eg. mypage3.php and mypage6.php)

On the first place, I thought it just some PHP 'memory_limit' issue, so I tried to solve it by re-configuring (increase from 128M) the memory_limit up to 160M then 192M, but it still failed. Then I tried to find out how much my PHP script consume (or allocate) memory, by using memory_get_peak_usage(true) which returns 4,194,304 (it is the max value acquired from mypage2.php - mypage7.php). Doing some test again, the error seems to happen randomly (sometimes all of the pages loaded successfully, and sometimes 1 or 2 or 3 pages failed with the same error message).

Which lead me to think, the possibility of Apache's keep-alive configuration, so I checked it, it is active with timeout=5 and max=100, so I think its okay.. but still, I tried to set the HTTP header 'Connection: close' which still did not give me any solution.

Then, I tried to create this simple script, and upload this 'mypage1.php' script :

```
<?php
$param1 = isset($_GET['param1'])? $_GET['param1'] : '';

if($param1==='')
echo('<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mypage1.php?param1=aaa" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mypage1.php?param1=bbb" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mypage1.php?param1=ccc" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mypage1.php?param1=ddd" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mypage1.php?param1=eee" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mypage1.php?param1=fff" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mypage1.php?param1=ggg" ></script>
</head><body>');
else echo('/* javascript */');
?>
```

and this amaze me, even this simple script give me the same error 500 (... (12)Cannot allocate memory: ...)
This time I meet the dead-end. I dont think it related with the PHP memory issue (or, do you think so?). Please give me some feedback, ideas or any story based on your experience, what may cause this problem (or how to solve it).

edit:
the error 500 only occurs on some request (eg. mypage1.php?param1=ccc, mypage1.php?param1=fff)

Thank you

Comment: script type is expecting a .js file resource not a php. In your example above the returned data for a javascript page will have php headers.

Comment: have you checked /var/log/apach2/errors.log and /var/log/php... logs?to check if any error logged? also you must check your memory status and please tell us your OS

Comment: If you wish to run php from a javascript call use .htaccess file to direct from requested file type to php, then in your php file, output headers as javascript.

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^mypage1.js$ mypage1.php` <-- .htaccess . Top of php code page---> `header('Content-Type: application/javascript');`

Comment: @pokeybit good point of view, it should have the "header Content-Type:" to text/javascript in order for client web browser to aknowledge the response as a javascript, but I think it is not the issue here, because some request (eg. mypage1.php?param1=aaa, mypage1.php?param1=bbb) returns HTTP 200 (eventhough it should be corrected as you said) as I see them in my webbrowser network console. (in my production problem case, it is PHP which returns JSON data)

Comment: The code works fine on my server with no error 500. maybe your server is throttling connections which would tie into the inconsistencies you experience, such as it errors for param1=ccc and param1=fff, every two calls in X amount of time causes a block. Try adding `echo('/* javascript */');sleep(1);`

Comment: @EbrahimPoursadeqi from my cPanel errors log, it said "server error log: Mon Jul 03 01:50:07.747401 2017] [:error] [pid 612239:tid 139731694188288] (12)Cannot allocate memory: [client x.x.x.x:x] couldn't create child process: /usr/sbin/suphp for /xxx ..." and I could not find any errors.log file, the cPanel server information gives me memory used 26.58%, Swap16.67%, from the phpinfo() gives me System:Linux Server API:CGI/FastCGI, memory_limit (local) 192M (master) 32M, and because it should be my new server/webhosting, it not active yet (only me and several users access it for testing)

Comment: Adding sleep(1); is a bad workaround sorry, Try adding async to all those javascript calls. `<script async type="text/javascript" src="mypage1.php?param1=aaa" ></script>`

Comment: @pokeybit I have added the "else {echo('/* javascript */'); sleep(1);}", tried to upload, and view the result in my webbrowser network console, it still happens (sometimes 3 requests return error 500, sometimes 5 requests return error 500, and sometime 2 requests, ...) yes, I agree it is inconsistencies.. but I have no idea what may cause it. any other idea?

Comment: @R.K Yeah the sleep thing won't fix it as it's just delaying the time it takes for file to return. You need to throttle your calls to that page. Try the async.

Comment: @pokeybit async didnt work too... I think the problem when the request reach to the webserver, the webserver (I'm not sure the Apache or PHP) give error 500 because of some sort of limit (if any), if 1 "same" connection in the same time request greater than X times then give some error, or somesort. I tried to modify the script, so the client webbrowser will give 'delay' for 1000 ms after each javascript request, and it give 100% HTTP 200, but when I reduce into 10 ms, it still gives some HTTP 500, any idea?

Comment: @R.K yes that's my conclusion. Use that method or contact your host to increase available threads/sessions per user.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I see that you want to secure some javascripts, right?
It's very bad idea to do validate like this, cause imported (returned by the param) script can be too big to read by the browser and by the server too.

It can throw HTTP 500, cause server cannot parse that kind of big response.

The best solution for this is create simple switch inside mypage1 which directly points (and includes) requested javascript file :)

Additionaly You can create 1 more php file (simple router for the javascripts) and inside this file you can check that param - after this you can include specified JS or just return JS file name to include it by the main php file :)

Comment: in my real PHP script, the "javascript request" is a JSON XMLHttpRequest to my another PHP file. I'm affraid my goal is not to secure my javascript, I just create a new simple scenario which give the exactly same error, which I think some sort of "if 1 same connection in a same time requests for more than a limit, then return error". Because the error 500 is inconsistency (sometimes happen in 2 requests, sometimes 3 request, etc.) But I just can not figure it out, what setting, or where (either Apache or PHP). Any ideas?